# regex: getting all matches for group

Tags: python, regex

in python, i'm trying to extract all time-ranges (of the form HHmmss-HHmmss) from a string. i'm using this python code.

```
text = "random text 0700-1300 random text 1830-2230 random 1231 text"
regex = "(.*(\d{4,10}-\d{4,10}))*.*"
match = re.search(regex, text)
```

this only returns `1830-2230` but i'd like to get `0700-1300` and `1830-2230`. in my application there may be zero or any number of time-ranges (within reason) in the text string. i'd appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `re.findall` to find all matches ([Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/Cw1mJ9/1)):

```py
import re

text = "random text 0700-1300 random text 1830-2230 random 1231 text"
pat = r"\b\d{4,10}-\d{4,10}\b"

for m in re.findall(pat, text):
    print(m)
```

Prints:

```
0700-1300
1830-2230
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex.

```
(\d{4}-\d{4})
```

All you need is pattern {four digts}minus{ four digits}. Other parts are not needed.